# How to tell who is logged in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have made a working login and signup page in PHP but I ran into a problem. I don't know how to get the id of the person who is logged onto their computer. How do I make where it keeps track of who is logged in on what computer and displays there information to them?

For instance, on Facebook it always knows who you are and displays what you alone are supposed to see, but how is this done? How does it keep track of this? I'm sorry if this is hard to understand but I can't really explain it.

Comment: By storing values in a database.

Comment: Make use of Sessions. http://in1.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: You store information about a user in a database, retrieve them when a person logs in, store information in sessions. [Take a look here](http://phpsnips.com/4/Simple-User-Login#.UmOOMpGR_io)

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to Stack Overflow. We _are_ keen to help beginners, but on the other hand, we do really need to see some prior effort and research. We would otherwise be swamped with a large number of unresearched questions. If you could do some web searching for this problem, that would help you enormously - try "PHP user session", "PHP logon system" in your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

A session is a way to store information (in the form of variables) to be used across multiple pages.

```
<?php 
 // this line starts the session and must be present in any page where you need to set or retrieve a session variable
 session_start(); 
 
 // this sets variables in the session 
 $_SESSION['userid']='123'; //obv it will be dynamic
 
 // this retrieves the value set earlier
 echo $_SESSION['userid'];
 ?>
```

So you can check on every page if the `userid` exist in the `database` you can fetch its record.

Answer (score 1):

All the three inline-comments are valid answers for different scenarios.

1. If you want to permanently remember the logged in user - use Databases
2. If you want your browser to remember the logged in user for a defined period - use [Cookies](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/qt/php_cookie.htm)
3. If you want your browser to remember the logged in user till your browser is closes - use [Sessions](http://krisnaordinary.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/creating-a-simple-login-logout-session-using-php/)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into session variables. A PHP session variable is used to store information about, or change settings for a user session. Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application.

When they log in you set a session variable for their username (or whatever variable you want) then when they change page you look for the session variable, get their username and display the relevant data. When they log out you destroy the session variable. If they load a page and the session variable does not exist they are not logged in.

Here is a short tutorial for you:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Answer (score 0):

A unique user ID is assigned in sign up for the site, so when the user logs in this user ID is requested and the users session is assigned to this ID which makes it easy to retrieve all data relevant to the current user. Have a look into user sessions..

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol which means it doesn't have any history of previous call made by same user. So to bring in context information to the HTTP request, UI/browser sends some information to uniquely identify each user.

So server component (Java/PHP) identifies user through this extra information. And ofcourse it finds it out through the help of DB.